# Using Japanese characters with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, japan

I am writing a program to access the shapefile with attributes with Japanese characteristics, and I want to use setSubsetString(SQL inquiry).

When the SQL inquiry contains the Japanese characters, It does not work well.
Such as " year=2004 AND 事故類型=その他" in this case, I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: you should force the string to be a unicode string, something like: query=ur" year=2004 AND 事故類型=その他"

Comment: The original of the shaplefile is in SHIFT_JIS. So it does not work well.